# New CPU, bleeps - Don't have a clue

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

I have a [the following desktop](http://support.hp.com/th-en/document/c02027491)

Computer: HP Compaq Presario CQ5305UK
Motherboard: H-I41-uATX (Eton/EtonL)
Power Supply: 260W
Graphics Card: Nvidia GeForce GT 720 - 2GB
Processor: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU - E5300
RAM: 4GB DDR3

I have just purchased a new CPU, an [Intel Core2 Quad Q8400 CPU 2.6GHz](http://ark.intel.com/products/38512/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q8400-4M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB)

**After installing the CPU, it just bleeps. One small bleep, then one long. It continues to do this until I turn off the computer.**

I have researched google but couldn't find anything in regards to it.

I don't want to send back the processor due to knowing that it's compatible with my motherboard, as it states so on [this link](http://support.hp.com/th-en/document/c01903990)

```
Motherboard supports the following processor upgrades:

Core 2 Quad Q8xx0/Q9xx0 (Yorkfield core) (95W)
Core 2 Duo E8xx0 (Wolfdale core) (65W)
Core 2 Duo E7xx0 (Wolfdale core) (65W)
Pentium Dual Core E5xx0 (Wolfdale core) (65W)
Celeron Dual Core E1xx0 (Conroe core) (65W)
Celeron 4xx series (Conroe core) (35W)
```

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: 1) The beep codes are usally in the manual, do you still have that?
2) Are you running the latest motherboard firmware? asking because later older BIOS versions might not support relative new CPU's

Comment: I haven't got the manual but I've looked on the motherboard manual online, but it doesn't state anything as such as the beeps that it's giving out. I also can't seem to find the BIOS drivers anywhere :/

Comment: 1 short + 1 long is a memory error.

Comment: I've got the same memory in the PC now which is working, so I don't see how it can be anything related to it. I've also changed the RAM slot with the other CPU in the PC, which didn't resolve anything.

Comment: The FSB speed from the new CPU has a higher speed. IIRC that also involved memory access. [comparsion of both CPU's](http://ark.intel.com/compare/35300,38512).

Comment: In that case, what could I do to repair the issue to be able to use the CPU? :)

Comment: if you have the same memory, replaced a CPU that you know is compatable, and get memory errors specific, keep in mind that the cpu socket connects the memory up also. This pins problem can be caused pretty easily in the new stuff, not so often in the 775 at all, but could be a concideration, including offset heatsync clamping.  Beyond that, you could go back to your old working configuration, set your memory Way Way down, using rate and timing, then switch to the new, and adjust up from there.

Comment: Could you give me a bit more of an insight as to what I need to do to attempt to fix it please?

Comment: Beep codes are usually related to the company that wrote the BIOS, so that 's the place to search for them. The BIOS usually displays this info on boot.

Comment: I've checked the seating of all objects inside of the computer on the MOBO. It doesn't seem to be making a difference.

Comment: Would getting different RAM or PSU affect this at all?

Comment: @iGetty - The memory you know works, so its unlikely the memory, so getting different memory won't change anything.  This isn't a problem that it is linked to a PSU.

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm confused as to what I am able to do to get my CPU working then as I don't know what steps to take :(

Comment: The error is an indication that the CPU itself is the problem, likely caused by a bent pin, since the problem didn't exist until you installed the CPU.

Comment: @Ramhound - That's weird because it's a brand new CPU, straight out of the box into the PC and it's not done anything but beep at me :(

Comment: If installed incorrectly, the pins, can easily be bent.

Comment: How can I check whether pins are bent, etc?

Comment: Perform a visual inspection.

Comment: I have done so and they don't look bent. Here's an image: http://imgur.com/W5kszZz

Comment: Its LGA, The pins are on the socket, not the chip

Comment: Oh. Well, my other processor is inside of the PC now and it's working - that is what I am using to type now. So I don't think that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Just checked my system RAM currently;

I have currently got 4GB 399MHz RAM, and the processor is 1366 MHz, could that be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

While there are beep codes that are supposed to reflect certain kinds of errors, re-seat the RAM and try again.  The codes read "Motherboard Power issue" but are really more like, "Mobo power circuit, but if not try the ram anyway."

If RAM reseats don't do it, reduce everything to only:

1. Mobo,
2. CPU power cable,
3. CPU,
4. Mobo Power Cable,
5. one stick of RAM.

See if it boots to "no OS found."  If so, add another component and boot again.

Comment: I've tried all of them, no matter what happens it just keeps beeping.

I've removed EVERYTHING except RAM and CPU, still beeps, I've also tried without RAM and it's still beeping.

Comment: It's supposed to beep without RAM; my arrangement above is the minimum.  Try only one stick (or a different stick) in the lowest-numbered-"A"-lettered slot.  Sometimes a stick is just bad in such a way that it can never be seated correctly, and sometimes a motherboard refuses to recognize something in the B channel if the A is not occupied.

Comment: I've checked that mate with no luck :(

Comment: Pull the BIOS battery and let it reset that.  Sometimes that will resurrect a board.  From here on, the only options you have are reseat components adnaseum, or (the correct solution:), try known good parts to verify functionality for your parts.

Comment: I've re-seated and know all the parts are working as they're in use right now with my old CPU.

I've removed the CMOS battery and replaced it an hour later, but nothing happened.

Comment: Look for bent pins in the mobo socket.  You're sure both CPUs work for that socket, right?  (LGA1155 is not at all the same as LGA1150.)  I presume you matched the orientation arrows and that you didn't smear gobs of thermal paste into cracks around the CPU.  At this point I regret to inform you that you have a bad board.  Sorry; try RMA procedures to get a new one.

Comment: I have looked but can't see anything. Bot CPUs are LGA775 Socket T, I actually got the CPU recommendation from the HP website itself whom provide the computer, and it states that it's perfectly fine on there. The old CPU works perfectly fine (E5300) but the new one is just being an absolute pain in the ass. I didn't put loads of Thermal on, just a pea-sized blob which spread just before the edges of the CPU.

By RMA, what do you mean?

Comment: RMA is basically warranty return to the place you ordered (newegg.com or whatever).  You send them a note about the parts being dead-on-arrival and they reply with shipping instructions or send you a box sometimes.  I looked at your reply to Ramhound earlier; did you take a picture (from several angles) of the CPU socket and its pins?  They are what can get bent.

Comment: The socket is still in working order as I have the current CPU inside of it, it's just not working with the new CPU. If there's anything you'd like to see/know, please ask - I could really do with this working as it's frustrating me lol.

Comment: Oh the CPU is the new component; I misread.  I correct my previous statement:  You have a bad new CPU, not a bad board.  There is nothing further to do unless you have another board compatible with that CPU, but that's just for confirmation of a diagnosis you have carved the outlines of very thoroughly.

Comment: That's rather annoying. Two different CPU's have done the exact same thing, it's like I just can't upgrade. Could it possibly be due to the fact that the new CPU is 1333MHz and my ram is only 399MHz, or that my CPU is only 260w and not enough power getting through?

Comment: Any clues mate?

Comment: It might be worth a try booting the good cpu, then seeing if you can set the memory clock rate lower.  Some BIOS' will let you do that in advanced settings, overclocking, or similar deeper menus.  If you can set a lower clock rate, then put the newer CPU in, perhaps that will do it.  You could also try to borrow a stick of higher speed.  Don't be too concerned about it though; backwards compatibility is a thing here.  Your 1333MHz is designed to dual-channel two 666 MHz sticks, so two 399 MHz is really dual-channeling up to 800MHz.

Comment: Power is probably only an issue if you're running an 8-pin CPU power slot with a 4-pin plug or a 20-pin mobo power Plug in a 24-pin power slot.

Comment: I don't understand the last part lol, also - I am only using one 399 MHz stick of RAM and that's it. Could that be the issue?

Comment: http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=116936&d=1349303491  This motherboard has an 8-pin power slot, but the cord in the picture is 4-pin only.  Sometimes this will still work, but other times the CPU isn't getting enough power.  Similarly, there are 20-pin and 24-pin Motherboard power slots:  http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/a/atx-24-pin-connector.jpg       The 399MHz stick should be fine.  You could look for a 666MHz if you wanted to be absolutely sure that wasn't the problem.  I doubt it, though; the clock rates are backwards compatible.

Comment: So it could be related to the motherboard not being correct, or the leads on the PSU not being enough due to the lack of power? Also, the motherboard having that extra slot for the CPU could be needed to have the power? Could that cause the beeps that the new CPU is giving to me?

Answer (score 2):

According to HP one short and one long beep is a memory issue

[image]

[Source](http://support.hp.com/th-en/document/bph07107#AbT1)

Comment: It's really strange as the RAM is working how it should be at the minute with a different CPU installed? What could the issue be there, new CPU causes memory to fail?

Comment: The CPU has memory on board, the code definition is not clear what memory. If putting the old cpu in corrects the issue then I suspect a bad or incorrectly installed  cpu.

Comment: On this image ( New CPU - http://imgur.com/W5kszZz ) the pins are different to the old CPU ones, in different locations, could that be related? (the 5 thicker/bigger looking ones)

Comment: Post an image of the old cpu please

Comment: http://imgur.com/bX2KW3S - That's the old one.

Comment: iGetty, the 5 thicker/bigger looking ones are not pins, those are electronic components that have nothing to do with the connection of the CPU to the socket.  The dot grid is where the mobo pins contact the CPU, and they are the same.  The components being different is no matter.

Answer (score 0):

a little bit late, but I had the same problem, now solved: It's exactly what the board 'says': the memory-modules! One short, one long beep.

Whereas the Intel Dualcore 2x2.8 Ghz runs with 2x 2GB 10600U-09-11-A1, the Intel Q9650 (for example) dosn't!

It needs 10600U-09-10-A0 chips to run!

Regards
NewOrder